# In a custom html form of SQLFORM in web2py, how to copy the request argument of the url into a form field input?

Tags: html, web2py

***The code of my model db.py is:***

```
db.define_table(
                'event_table',
                Field('event_name'),
                Field('organizer_name'),
                )

db.define_table('category',
                Field('Category_name',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('Event_id',db.event_table)
                )
```

***The controller looks like:***

```
def category():

    form=SQLFORM(db.category)
    if form.process().accepted:
        response.flash='form has accepted'
    else:
        response.flash='form has errors'
    return dict()
```

***The code for the view (default/category.html) is:***

```html
{{extend 'layout.html'}}



  <form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<ul>
    
  <li>category name: <input name="Category_name" value="{{=request.args(0)}}"/></li>
  <li>event_id type: <input name="Event_id" ></li>
</ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  


  
</form>
```

**(Here I am trying to pass the event id through the request argument of the URL. But when I submit the form, it says "form has errors". Why is that happening? I am not able to understand.?)**

Comment: Do you know what the error is? Likely it is coming from the `Event_id` input, as that is a reference field, so the submitted value must be the integer ID of a record from the `event_table` table. The `Event_id` input is just a text input, so the user is not likely to know the record ID of the related event. Consider instead defining the form elements in the view via the [custom forms interface](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Custom-forms). Also, you can define a default value like this: `db.category.Category_name.default = request.args(0)`.

Comment: Thankyou, it really helped.